# Drawing a circle of unknown number of circles

Tags: c#, drawing

I am currently working on a WinForms app, which at some point has to draw some stuff. Basically, it has to draw an unknown number of circles (f.e 3, 5, 10) in organized in a shape of a circle. Something like this:

[image]

I know it looks horrible. So I thought about defining a center of a circle and a radius. Then I just have to go f.e from the top of the big circle and draw a small circle every x-degrees (like for 3 circles it would be 120 degrees, for 4 circles 90 degrees etc.).

My question here is: Is there an algorithm, which would give me the center point of a circle to draw? Like I define my big circle with f.e center `X = 50, Y = 50` and a radius `R = 10`. And then I draw a circle at the top, decide that I want to draw the next one 120 degrees far from the first one and I just need a point (X, Y) which is on the big circle?

Comment: That algorithm would be `Math.Sin` or `Math.Cos`.

Comment: I think what you want is to draw lots of small circles to form a large circle. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The problem is not drawing, the problem is finding X and Y

Comment: You are looking for a Centroid of a polygon.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need some math to figure out the coordinate of where the angle lands at the end of perimeter of the circle (a distance of the radius of the circle from the center of the circle). Here's psuedocode for this situation.

```
var center = new Point(0,0);
var radius = 5;
var degrees = 83;
var angle = Math.PI * degrees / 180;
var xPos = center.X + (radius * Math.cos(angle));
var yPos = center.Y + (radius * Math.sin(angle));
var newPosition = new Point(xPos,yPos);
```

Here, `newPosition` becomes the center point for the circled you'll be drawing along your imaginary circle. As for gathering the angles, simply use `360 / count * index`.

Comment: But doesn't `Math.sin()` accept angles in radians, not in degrees?

Comment: I did kinda the same thing while I was waiting for an answer, but still, thanks for the advice!